# Como exibir alerta após erro de um eval()?

Tags: javascript, eval

Eu tenho uma calculadora que funciona mais ou menos assim:

```
[bolas][+][preco da bola]
```

Eu varro a string substituindo [XXXXXXX] pelo valor correspondente e utilizo o eval para realizar o calculo. Mas pode haver casos de erro quando por exemplo o calculo fica assim:

```
eval("5 + [preco da bola]");
```

- O código JS para quando ocorre esse erro?
- Se o código parar tenho como previnir isso para que continue rodando?
- Posso detectar o erro e enviar um alert personalizado?

Comment: boa pergunta! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso?....

```
try{
    eval("5 + [preco da bola]");
}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes sempre fazer um erro não passar para o lado do cliente com:

```
try{
    // o código que pode dar erro aqui
}
catch(erro){
    // este codigo é corrido quando houver erros. A variável "erro" contêm o código do erro
}
```

Acho no entanto que seria mais interessante fazer isso sem eval, se quiseres ajuda tens de dar mais detalhes.

Comment: porque se eu coloco 5 + [xxx] sem o eval o javascript não leva para o Cacth?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo faz um jsFiddle para poder ajudar melhor. Senão vou estar a adibinhar o que queres. `5 + [xxx]` dá um erro de *parse*, não um erro em *runtime*.

Comment: Acho que esse seu comentário já responde. Erros de parse não tem como previnir entao ne?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo exato. Isso dá erro antes mesmo de o script correr.